# How to use my location to calculate distance between two points using latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to get my REST API to only send me back items that are within a certain radius. I've written code to calculate the distance between two points and only send me the ones within the desired radius. However, as of now I'm using an arbitrary latitude and longitude as the point of comparison. How can I implement using my own location into this algorithm?

```
app.get('/posts', function(req, res) { 

// Get 'posts' collection from db
db.collection('posts', function(err, collection) { 

    // Get all documents in the 'posts' collection
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {

        // Documents to send back
        var results = []

//Function that calculates distance between two points.
    function calculateDistance (lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2) {
        var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  
        var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
        var a = 
            (Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2))
            ; 
        var c = (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))); 
        var d = (6371 * c); // Distance in km
        var e = (d/1.6) //Convert distance in km to miles.
            return e 
    }

        // Iterate over each document and check if the distance is correct
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i]
             if ((calculateDistance(item.latitude, 43.7035798, item.longitude, -72.2887838) > 25)) {
                 results.push(item)
             }

        }          
        res.send(results);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Any reason not to use MongoDB's [**`$near`** operator with **`$maxDistance`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) set?

Answer (score 1):

navigator.geolocation is what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

In Firefox at least, you should get a popup that asks if you want to allow your browser to send your location.  You've probably have gotten them for websites that use the Google Maps API.